# Is there a way to round a decimals that i get in the coefficients of the function poly.calc?

Tags: r, rounding

I'm working with the poly.calc() function to interpolate some points, the problem is that I need to print the polynomial with maximum two decimals for each coefficient

I know that in R there is a function like round (...) and it can do this but with numbers, i don't know if it works with the expression that i get from poly.calc().

A example:

```
library(PolynomF)

x=c(1:4)
y=c(15,12,14,17)

pol = poly.calc(x,y)
pol
```

This is the result:

> 27 - 17.83333*x + 6.5*x^2 - 0.6666667*x^3

And i need something like this:

> 27 - 17.83*x + 6.5*x^2 - 0.66*x^3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make use of the `round`

```
library(PolynomF)
pol <- round(pol, 2)
pol
#27 - 17.83*x + 6.5*x^2 - 0.67*x^3
```

#### data

```
pol <- poly_calc(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd try to use the round function as shown in following example and edit for your needs:

```
# --- calculate parameters lm -----------------------------------------
model <- lm(Pegel$D00 ~ Pegel$dss)
# summary(model)
a = round(as.vector(coef(model)[1]), 2)
b = round(as.vector(coef(model)[2]*365), 2) # scaled for year
r2 = round(summary(model)$r.squared, 2)
```